# SQL convert integer columns to time and add them

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a newbie, so please help ...

I have two columns in a table:

Hours, Minutes (they are both integer type)
so they have ordinary integer values, like:

```
Hours   Minutes 
---------------
 1        30
 0        20
 2         0
```

etc

I need to combine these two columns into a third column and add them up:

like `1:30` (one hr and 30 min)

how can I do this?

Comment: please tag your database

Comment: how do I do that? I dont understand. Those are two integer columns and I need to display and add them like hours and minutes

Comment: Too many dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes do date/time. Which dbms are you using? Do you want time data type, or character data type?

Comment: Also, don't store time values like that in two different columns. Have 1 column, time data type!

Comment: How about converting minutes to decimal and store 1:30 as 1.5?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 SELECT CAST(Hours AS Varchar)+':'+CAST(Minutes AS Varchar) From Table_Name
```

Comment: + is product specific, but for which dbms? (Note that no dbms is specified.)

Comment: Do you need the result to be in time format, or just a string as shown here?

Comment: I need a result in time format... if two columns hold integer values like hour:2 and minute:30 .... I need a third select column to look like 2:30 ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this using the TIME datatype. The time datatype is NOT designed to hold the value of how long something lasted. It is designed to hold the value of a specific point in time.

Consider what would happen when you exceed 24 hours. If you want too add these up just use simple addition.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    MyHours int,
    MyMinutes int
)

insert #Something
select 1, 30 union all
select 0, 20 union all
select 2, 0 union all
select 3, 45


select SUM(MyHours) + SUM(MyMinutes) / 60 as TotalHours
    , SUM(MyMinutes) % 60 as TotalMinutes
from #Something
```

Comment: Shouldn't `SUM(MyHours) + SUM(MyMinutes) / 60 as TotalHours` be `SUM(MyHours) + SUM(MyMinutes) / 60 + SUM(MyMinutes) % 60 as TotalHours`?

Comment: @Junaid don't think so. The sum of hours plus the sum of minutes divided by 60 would be the total number of hours. You are proposing that we add in the number of hours in MyMinutes a second time.

Answer (score 1):

**How about this:**

```
SELECT SUM(Hours + (Minutes / 60)) FROM Table
```

Comment: Remove SUM for each ROW rather than totalled result set.